# Any reason to use shareReplay(1) in a BehaviorSubject pipe?

Tags: rxjs

I'm using a library that exposes data from a service class using a pretty common `BehaviorSubject` pattern. The only notable difference with the implementation and what I have seen/used myself is the addition of a `pipe` with a `shareReplay(1)` operator. I'm not sure if the `shareReplay` is required. What effect, if any, does the `shareReplay` have in this case?

```
// "rxjs": "^6.3.0"
this.data = new BehaviorSubject({});
this.data$ = this.data.asObservable().pipe(
   shareReplay(1) 
)
```

Note: I've read a number of articles on shareReplay, and I've seen questions about different combinations of shareReplay and Subject, but not this particular one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not in your example but imagine if there was some complex logic in a map function that transformed the data then the share replay would save that complex logic being run for each subscription.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { map, shareReplay } = rxjs.operators;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('initial value');

const obs$ = bs$.pipe(
  map(val => {
    console.log('mapping');
    return 'mapped value';
  }),
  shareReplay({bufferSize:1, refCount: true})
);

obs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

obs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Compare without the share, the map happens twice.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const bs$ = new BehaviorSubject('initial value');

const obs$ = bs$.pipe(
  map(val => {
    console.log('mapping');
    return 'mapped value';
  })
);

obs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });

obs$.subscribe(val => { console.log(val); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this pattern (use of `shareReplay(1)`), the service protects itself from the user using the `next()` function of the BehaviorSubject while sending the last value of the BehaviorSubject (which would not have been the case without `shareReplay(1)`).